# Power BI Measure past due order using dates in two different tables

Tags: powerbi

Request: Calculate the number of Purchased Orders past due. Recalculate when filters applied.

Background: Have 3 tables:

- Purchase_Orders containing order [Promise Date],
- Received_Orders containing [Received Date],
- PO_DIM containing unique Purchase Order Numbers.

Relation: **Purchase_Orders *-1 PO_DIM 1-* Received_Orders

Measure Sudo Code:

```
 1. CountRows
 2. Filter for rows where Purchase_Orders[Promised Date] is not Blank()
 3. Filter for rows where Received_Orders[Received Date] is Blank()
 4. Filter for rows where Purchase_Orders[Promised Date] < Today()
```

How would you solve?

[image: Link to my code and error]

Comment: Your #2 Filter is probably redundant, given #4 Filter.

Answer (score 0):

I would roll the 3 Filter requirements into one FILTER function, using RELATED to test columns from other tables, something like:

```
Count PO Pastdue =
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( 'PO_DIM' ),
    FILTER (
        'PO_DIM',
        NOT ( ISBLANK ( RELATED ( Purchase_Orders[Promised Date] ) ) )
            && ISBLANK ( RELATED ( Received_Orders[Received Date] ) )
            && RELATED ( Purchase_Orders[Promised Date] ) < TODAY ()
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, however, that does not work. I get the error "The column 'FHM_F_Purchase_Orders[Promised Date]' either doesn't exist or doesn't have a relationship to any table available in the current context."  There has to be an issue with the relationship.  I just can't figure it out.  Each table relates individually to PO_DIM fine.

Comment: Post a screen-shot of your Relationship view.

Comment: New to the site.  Don't have ability to post images